# How to debug multiple JUnit test suites in Netbeans?

Tags: java, debugging, testing, netbeans, junit

I use Netbeans 7.0.1 (and JUnit 4) and have a java project with several test suites in different packages. I can run all tests by Alt+F6 or right-click on project and choose "Test". Also, I can debug each test file separately by Ctrl+Shift+F6 or right-click on project and choose "Debug Test File". But apparently it is not possible to debug the test files all together at once. Ctrl+Shift+F6 does not work if the project or multiple test files are selected and if I right-click on project there is no option to debug test files.

In Eclipse, however there is such option easily by right-click on project and "Debug As" -> "JUnit Test"

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8):

I am using netbeans 7.2 and it have the option "Debug tests files" in context menu. But you have to select all test files which you want to run (CTRL + left click) and then right click and select this option. It was good enough for me, bud i didn´t figure out how to debug all tests.

Comment: I cannot do that in my multi-module project. I retrieve: 'Error: Could not find or load main class @{argLine}'

Comment: Maybe you can try netbeans 7.2. I haven't been coding in java for 3 years now so I can't help you with details :(

Comment: I found the solution: removing <argline> content in pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

To debug/test the entire project I

1. right clicked on the project
2. chose properties
3. chose actions
4. updated test project with these properties:

test=${packageClassName}
forkMode=once
maven.surefire.debug=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}
jpda.listen=true

Comment: What I should put in ${packageClassName} and ${jpda.address}

Comment: The string "test=${packageClassName}
forkMode=once
maven.surefire.debug=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}
jpda.listen=true" is literal.You do not need to replace ${packageClassName} with anything